# Why Mongodb collection is not connecting via connect your application?

Tags: mongodb, express, collections, atlas

When i try with mongoose ,it connects. But whrn i am tring with connect with your application and mongoclient this code does not work. But this code is in their documnetation. Why Mongodb collection is not connecting via connect your application?

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const password = "Kr6bdMTskY3rYwF4";

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello i am working')
})

const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://organicUser:Kr6bdMTskY3rYwF4@cluster0.iz1nfji.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("organicdb").collection("products");
    // perform actions on the collection object
    console.log("Database connected");
    client.close();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Why Mongodb collection is not connecting via connect your application?

Comment: do not post real name and password in public places like SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Express application is working but you forgot the app.listen function. You need to assign a port to your app and make it listen to that port. Also your Mongodb error is solved.

```js
const express = require('express');

const PORT = 3000;
const app = express();
const password = "Kr6bdMTskY3rYwF4";

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello i am working')
})

const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://organicUser:Kr6bdMTskY3rYwF4@cluster0.iz1nfji.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });

async function run() {
  try {
    const database = client.db("organicdb");
    const collection = database.collection("products");
    // perform actions on the collection object
    console.log(collection);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: Sorrry i forgot to add this code in my question,. I added "app.listen(3000);" in my code. But this does not work

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Your code works fine. I think the main problem was, not using async function. Thanks again